# How to search nearby coordinates in android using google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'am new in android development my problem is.
I have to find nearby coordinates from a data in a given radius in android.
For example when i click a button. It will search nearby coordinates listed in an array or in a database.

Example: My current coordinates is 1.1
Nearby coordinates will show : 1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5 which is stored or from my database/array.

Is this possible? Can someone help me. Any answer is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: anything and everything is possible, please google on how to access data from array or how to use rest api to get data from server in android. I think the domain of your question is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to simply use a geographical distance function.
Have a look at: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

This will give you some background information on what you are trying to do.  I've used this website *many* times during work with UAVs.  Also, keep in mind that you might need to convert to/from Deg/Min/Sec Lat & Longitude <-> decimal Latitude/Longitude.

Find the method for calculating distance - and there are many coded examples already out there - and then run each of your target points through it to find out how far each is from you.

Good luck!